# C# Identity Server 4. Ошибка duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UserNameIndex" при смене пароля

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

У меня есть функционал смены пароля. Раньше работало все без проблем, но сейчас появилась ошибка "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UserNameIndex"" и я не могу понять что не так. Пользователь с данным UserName и NormalizedUserName один в БД. Прошу Вас подсказать, куда можно посмотреть, чтобы поскорее решить текущую проблему. Мой код:

```
public async Task Reset(
    ResetPasswordCommand command,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var user = await _userManager
        .FindByEmailAsync(command.Email)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    //падает ниже
    var result = await _userManager
        .ResetPasswordAsync(user, command.Token, command.Password)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Join(";", result.Errors));
    }
}
```

Comment: Смотреть метод `ResetPasswordAsync`. Смотреть схему БД.

Comment: Намекну, что мы бы не отказались посмотреть этот метод и схему.